# topnavbar dropdown on hover dissapears too quickly React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Okay, i am new to css styling as i generally work more on backend. i was designing a website using react and i have run into a rather common issue, where when i try to hover over a navbar item, the dropdown shows but dissapears too quickly.

I have browsed the stackoverflow questions but none of them seem to work. Here is the code for my `navitem.js` :

```
import React from "react";
import "./NavBarItem.css";
import { IoIosArrowDown } from "react-icons/io";
const NavBarItem = props => {
  let navItem = (
    <div className="navitem">
      {props.icon}
      {props.navtext}
    </div>
  );

  if (props.dropdownItems) {
    navItem = (
      <div className="navitem">
        <button className="dropdownbutton">
          {" "}
          {props.icon}
          {props.navtext}
          <IoIosArrowDown className="dropdownicon" />
        </button>
        <div className="dropdownitems">
          {props.dropdownItems.map(dropdownItem => (
            <div className="dropdownitem" key={dropdownItem.key}>
              {dropdownItem.text}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return navItem;
};

export default NavBarItem;
```

and my `navitem.css` :

```
.navitem {
    display: inline-block;
    margin : 15px;
    cursor : pointer;
}

.icon {
    position : relative;
    top : 2px;
    right : 5px;
}

.dropdownicon {
    position : relative;
    top : 4px;
    left : 5px;
}

.dropdownitems {
    display: none;
    position : absolute;
    top : 55px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    background : linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(99, 25, 12, 0.8), rgba(226, 13, 13, 0.8));
    color : white;
    float: none;
    padding: 12px 0;
}

.dropdownbutton{
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  font-size : 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  cursor : pointer;
}

.navitem:hover .dropdownitems{
    display: block;
}

.dropdownitem {
    width : 9em;
    text-align: center;
    padding : 0;
    color : white;
}
```

the default solution had said that i have to wrap the button and icons in a div and add the :hover selector to that. If you look at my code, you will see that is exactly what i am doing here :

```
 /*Button and dropdown items wrapped inside navitem div */ 

 <div className="navitem"> 

         /* Button */

        <button className="dropdownbutton"> 
          {" "}
          {props.icon}
          {props.navtext}
          <IoIosArrowDown className="dropdownicon" />
        </button>

        /* Dropdown Items */

        <div className="dropdownitems"> 
          {props.dropdownItems.map(dropdownItem => (
            <div className="dropdownitem" key={dropdownItem.key}>
              {dropdownItem.text}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

and in my css i am doing this :

```
   .navitem:hover .dropdownitems{
    display: block;
    }

    .dropdownitems {
    display: none;
    position : absolute;
    top : 55px;
    margin-left: -35px;
    background : linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(99, 25, 12, 0.8), rgba(226, 13, 13, 0.8));
    color : white;
    float: none;
    padding: 12px 0;
    }
```

Here is a simple gif reproducing the issue :

[image: Navbar issue]

Any clue/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with the react. The issue is due to a gap between your top menu & the dropdown list. Exactly `top : 55px;` of the `dropdownitems` css class. This introduces a gap, so when you mouse over to that empty region, the dropdown menu disappears since you moved out of the menu element.

Remove the  `top : 55px;` and you should be fine. Heres the working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bbutp)

[image]

Comment: this was it. I reduced the top a bit and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

as above answer there is nothing big problem only minor space between your dropdown and link. It can solve with padding given to link or decrease margin-top of dropdown menu.
and also give line height to link.